# Duplicar varios Registros da Tabela de uma só vez

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Estou Desenvolvendo um sistema de pagamentos para minha empresa, onde há dois tipos diferentes de contas. Exporádicas (Ex. IPVA, Pen-Drive, etc.) e Fixas (Ex. Conta de Luz, Água, Telefone, Internet, etc.);

Tenho uma Tabela onde somente é exibido as contas com seu tipo='fixa'.

O que eu gostaria de realizar, que não consegui nem encontrei de modo algum foi...

um botão que pegaria os Dados que estão sendo exibidos nesta tabela e os duplicaria no BD com ID e Valor Diferentes.

A ideia é retirar o trabalho do usuario ficar relançando contas que terão dados exatamente iguais, talvez diferenciando vencimento e valor... e ao clicar no botão todos valores do tipo fixo serem duplicados...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que pode te ajudar, digamos que vc quer duplicar os dados do registro cujo id 1 com outro nome da conta:

```
INSERT INTO CONTAS (VENCIMENTO, NOMEDACONTA, CEDENTE, FIDELIDADE, CC, VALORULTIMACONTA) 
SELECT VENCIMENTO, 'Escreva o que deseja substituir', CEDENTE, FIDELIDADE, CC, VALORULTIMACONTA FROM CONTAS WHERE IDCONTA = '1';
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo =D, Deu Certo, Mas somente vai uma por vez, Como eu poderia duplicar todas de uma vez só?

Comment: Ué, roda uma query pra cada conta.

Comment: Ou modifique a condição `WHERE` se os dados a serem inseridos forem exatamente iguais

Answer (score 0):

Execute a query dentro de um loop for se o id for sequencial, e for realmente todos os valores.

```php
    $qnt_reg = mysqli_num_rows($query_select);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $qnt_reg; $i++) {
        //execute sua $query_insert aqui dentro mudando o id para $i se for sequencial; 
    };
```

Ou condicione quais serão os id selecionando pela query:

```php
$query_select = 'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE alguma coisa';
$query_rs = $conect->query($query_select);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_rs){
  //$id = $row['id'];
  $query_insert = "INSERT INTO table VALUES;
  $rs_insert = $conect->query($query_insert)
}
```